# Is there any way to layout buttons in circular arrangement?

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to make a round button in the corner and when you press on it, 3 buttons pop up around it. Something like Pinterest's menu when you hold on a pin. I've looked up using `UIBezierPath` but it's not what I'm looking for. I know there are GitHub libraries but I'm trying to make it from scratch.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to make from scratch:

[image: example]

I figured out how to make round buttons by using the corner radius. And I have a specific function that it's going to animate the buttons but I can't figure out how to properly get them in a circle. I used constraints but that makes more of a square layout than a round one.

Comment: Thank you, Rob. I figured out how to make round buttons by using the corner radius. And I have a specific function that it's going to animate the buttons but I can't figure out how to properly get them in a circle. I used constraints but that makes more of a square layout than a round one.

Comment: Well, you’re 90% of the way there! So, it’s just a little trigonometry to figure out where the center of the new buttons should be in relationship to the existing button. If _r_ is the distance from the x,y of the existing circle, and circle _i_ is at an angle of θᵢ, then xᵢ = x + r * cos(θᵢ) and yᵢ = y + r * sin(θᵢ). (In this arrangement angles are measured in radians from 3 o’clock, proceeding clockwise, or going negative to go counter clockwise.)

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thanks! Now my only problem is programmatically positioning all the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> but I can't figure out how to properly get them in a circle.

It’s just a little trigonometry to figure out where the center of the new buttons should be in relationship to the existing button. If *r* is the distance from the center *x*, *y* of the existing circle, and circle *i* is at an angle of *θᵢ*, then *xᵢ = x + r * cos(θᵢ)* and *yᵢ = y + r * sin(θᵢ)*. (In this arrangement angles are measured in radians from 3 o’clock, proceeding clockwise, or going negative to go counter clockwise.)

For example, if using constraints:

```
let r: CGFloat = 150               // let's say you want center of the circles to be 150 points away from center of existing button
let range = -CGFloat.pi / 2 ... 0  // and we want the angles to range from -π/2 to 0
let howMany = 5                    // and you want five of them

for i in 0 ..< howMany {
    let angle = range.lowerBound + CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(howMany - 1) * (range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    let offset = CGPoint(x: r * cos(angle), y: r * sin(angle))
    let button = ...
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(button)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainButton.centerXAnchor, constant: offset.x),
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainButton.centerYAnchor, constant: offset.y),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to animate the buttons with the effect I wanted. This was all very simple looking back on it.